# Line break when concatenating

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, line-breaks

Why when I do this?...

```
function addToList(URL)
{
    GetWebExceptions(); //defines GExceptionList
    GExceptionList = GExceptionList.concat(URL);
}
```

...and print the array into the debug console, the array adds automatically a line break between the second to last and last elements?

(If you didn't understand, it does this:)

```
Array: youtube.com,google.com,wikipedia.org
,4chan.org
```

Also, while looping through all the elements with another function, it finds an 'undefined' element after the one with the line break...

Answer (score 0):

It's because for some reason probably you add `'\n'` to your array. Try to initialize an array and push some strings into it. Also add `'\n'` and you will get the same effect like you described.